# JPA - Hibernate. ¿Cual es la mejor estrategia de generación de ids?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, teoría

Actualmente existen varias opciones disponibles para la generación de IDs de manera automática con Hibernate y JPA combinados.

Ejemplo: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

Estoy buscando documentación sobre cómo elegir la estrategia de generación de IDs específica que mejor se adapte a cada caso.

1-) ¿En qué se diferencian?

2-) ¿Porqué se elige una respecto a otra?

3-) ¿Funcionan todas las estrategias si hablamos de BBDD como Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**AUTO**

Indicates that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy for the particular database.

> Indica que el proveedor de la persistencia debe escoger la estrategia adecuada para cada base de datos en particular.

**IDENTITY**

Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column.

> Indica que el proveedor de la persistencia debe asignar la llave primaria para las Entities usando una columna de identificación en la base de datos.

**SEQUENCE**

Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database sequence.

> Indica que el proveedor de persistencia debe asignar llaves primarias para la "Entity" usando la secuencia de la base de datos

Este número secuencial es particular de algunas base de datos y lo que hace es crear un nuevo número que no se repite y retornarlo. La diferencia radica en que no hay aislamiento de transacción, por lo que varias transacciones no pueden obtener el mismo valor. [Más info de esto.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649102/what-is-a-sequence-database-when-would-we-need-it)

**TABLE**

Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using an underlying database table to ensure uniqueness.

> Indica que el proveedor de la persistencia debe asignar llaves primarias para la entidad usando tablas subyacentes para garantizar valores únicos.

Una tabla que te ayuda a llevar el control. [Más info.](https://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/generatedvalue-strategy-generationtype-table-hibernate)

---

Mucho tiene que ver la aplicación que vas a utilizar, pero para mí no ha sido necesario usar otra estrategia que `IDENTITY` cuando los valores son autonuméricos. Al final hibernate hace un buen trabajo y el objetivo es evitar depender de una tecnología de BD, que es una las características por las que trabajo con Spring Boot. No necesito preocuparme en la etapa de desarrollo sobre si habrá cambios en el gestor de BD o cosas de esas que suelen ser un dolor de cabeza.